# passing an array of character to function c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I have the following:

```
char cipan[9];
```

then what should I pass to the function? how about the get and set method??

I'm currently doing like this

set method

```
void setCipan(char cipan[]){

this->cipan = cipan;
}
```

and the get method

```
char getCipan(){
return cipan;
}
```

and I get an error when compiling??

Im totally blur.. can someone explain what should i pass to the function??

```
    class userData{
private:
    string name;
    char  dateCreate[9];

    void userDataInput(string name,char dateCreate[]){
        this->name = name;
        this->dateCreate = dateCreate;

    }
public:
    //constructor
    userData(string name){
        userDataInput(name,dateCreate);
    }
    userData(string name,char dateCreate[]){
        userDataInput(name,dateCreate);
    }
    //mutator methods
    void changeName(string name){this->name = name;}
    void changeDateCreate(char *dateCreate){this->dateCreate = dateCreate;}
    //accesor methods
    string getName(){return name;}
    char *getDateCreate(){return dateCreate;}


};
```

Comment: Paste the full code properly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: What is "the function" and what is "an error?"

Comment: The get method will need to be declared as `char*` won't it?

Comment: Why go through all troubles of using a char array ? Use a string instead and get all the library functions for free.

Comment: @user:  Better, but still not quite there.  Please edit your post to show a **minimally complete** example that I can copy-paste in to my compiler.  Also include the exact compiler error you're getting an an indication of where the error occurs.

Comment: Hello BumbCoder, im using array because i wanna use <time.h> which _strdate(array of char);

Comment: @user well you could use a string and at the point of the call to _strdate do `str.c_str()`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following:

```
void setCipan(const char* new_cipan)
{
    strcpy(cipan, new_cipan);
}

const char* getCipan() const
{
    return cipan;
}
```

Of course, the better approach is to use `std::string`:

```
void setCipan(const string& new_cipan)
{
    cipan = new_cipan;
}

string getCipan() const
{
    return cipan;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Constructor's purpose is to initialize class variables. I think it's unnecessary to call another method in the constructor to do initialization.

```
void userDataInput(string name,char dateCreate[]){
    this->name = name;
    this->dateCreate = dateCreate; // Both the dateCreate are class variables.
}

userData(string name){
    userDataInput(name,dateCreate); // dateCreate is already a class variable.
}
```

`dateCreate` is the class scope variable. You are just passing it to a method, and re-assigning the same to `dateCreate`. Assignment operation doesn't copy elements of one array to another and are invalid operations.

To copy array elements, use `std::copy` instead.